# Linear Algebra dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an argument about what is the correct answer for the question below:

We have four vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ such that each set of three of these vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

Now we given that $W = \operatorname{span}(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)$ with
\begin{align*}
w_1 &= v_1 + iv_2 - v_3\\
w_2 &= v_2+ iv_3 - v_4\\
w_3 &= iv_1 - v_4\\
w_4 &= iv_1 + v_2 + iv_3 - 2v_4
\end{align*}

The Question: What is the dimension of $W$?

The optional answers are:

- $1$
- $2$
- $3$
- $4$
- Can not be determined

**My attempt:**
At first I just used row operations and then got two rows of independent vectors so I did knew that $3$ and $4$ isn't the answer for sure. But - we are given that the set of 3 vectors are independent as I mention before. After a little bit of playing with those vectors, I got that $$v_4=-v_1+(1-i)v_2+(1+i)v_3.$$
After placing this $v_4$ as well in the matrix I got that I cannot determined if the dimension is $1$ or $2$, so my final answer is "can not be determined".

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Eliminating a few choices should be easy at the outset...

Comment: "I have an argument" What's your argument?

Comment: Copy-pasting a question to put on this site is not recieved well

Comment: At least you should copy the question correctly. Did you see “desmission” in the title?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm sorry for this but I'm new here... anyway, at first I just used row operations and then got two rows of independent vectors so I did knew that 1, 3 and 4 isn't the answer for sure. But - we given that the set of 3 vectors are independent as I mention before. After a little bit of playing with those vectors, I got that v4 is equal to -v1+v2(1-i)+v3(1+i). After place this v4 as well in the matrix I got that I cannot determined if the dimension is 1 or 2, so my final answer is "can not be determined".

Comment: What does mean by desmission?

Answer (score 2):

The dimension in general cannot be determined, it can be $1$ or $2$.

First notice that
$$w_3 = iw_1+w_2, \quad w_4 = iw_1+2w_2$$
so $\operatorname{span}\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\} = \operatorname{span}\{w_1,w_2\}$.

1. If $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly independent, then from $\alpha w_1+\beta w_2 =0$ we get
   $$0 = \alpha(v_1 + iv_2 - v_3)+\beta(v_2+ iv_3 - v_4) = \alpha v_1+(i\alpha+\beta)v_2+(-\alpha+i\beta)v_3-\beta v_4 \implies \alpha=\beta=0$$
   so $\{w_1,w_2\}$ is linearly independent.
2. If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent and e.g. $v_4 = -v_1+(1-i)v_2+(1+i)v_3$ then all four sets
   $$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{v_1,v_2,v_4\},\{v_1,v_3,v_4\},\{v_2,v_3,v_4\}$$
   are all linearly independent but
   $$w_2 = v_2+ iv_3 - v_4 = v_1 + iv_2 - v_3 = w_1$$
   so $\{w_1,w_2\}$ are clearly linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. This is what I thought. Although I suggested another way, it's the same idea. Thanks for your detailed solution.

Comment: @BipBipi No problem, I have edited your question to include your attempt from the comments otherwise it might be closed.